# AutoFilter Function is Deleting my Column Headers

Tags: excel, vba

I run my VBA code and the first time it runs I get the result I want but if I run it a second time my column headers get deleted. FYI my table starts on E and goes through N. My button is on column O and also gets deleted when I run it a second time.

Switching the Range did not help and setting AutoFilter to false also did not work. 
#

```
Sub Auto_filter()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HP Service Manager")
sh.AutoFilterMode = False
With sh
On Error Resume Next
.ShowAllData

.Range("E1:N1").AutoFilter 1, "IM*"
AutoFilter = False
End With
End Sub
```

#
Expect to not have column headers deleted.

Comment: Is there any other code that is running along with this? I created a test sheet and copied over your code and ran it multiple times. It does not delete any data at all. Moreover, the code itself does not have any statement to clear/delete data so just curious.

Comment: Yes lots of code running with this, but this is the last call on the button so I'm not exactly sure what could be deleting my column headers. I have a delete sub in my code but it only deletes blank rows. Which these are not.

Comment: Yea you are right it was my delete rows code. I troubleshooted it and it did disappear after my delete sub. Heres the code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the second code you shared.

The code is first setting the range here:

```
Set Rng = Range("E1", Cells(iRow, "E"))
```

And then here it is trying to delete all visible cells in the range (after applying the filter)

```
Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
```

which also includes your header cell.

So, a simple way to deal with it could be to set another range like this

```
Set Rng2 = Range("E2", Cells(iRow, "E"))
```

and then using it to delete the data

```
Rng2.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
```

Here is the re-written function for your reference. This only deletes the rows starting from row 2 that are blank. You may want to add some error handing in case there are no blank rows to delete etc.

```
Sub DeleteRowsAll()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim Rng As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Rows(1).Insert
Range("E1").Value = "rabbitohs"
With ActiveSheet
.UsedRange
iRow = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Set Rng = Range("E1", Cells(iRow, "E"))
Rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=""
Set Rng2 = Range("E2", Cells(iRow, "E"))
Rng2.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
.UsedRange
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That actually still deleted my column headers. I found a fix for it.

Comment: Sub DeleteRowsAll()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim CellValue As String

    LastRow = Worksheets("HP Service Manager").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
        CellValue = Worksheets("HP Service Manager").Cells(i, "E").Value

        If CellValue = "" Then
            Worksheets("HP Service Manager").Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub DeleteRowsAll()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim CellValue As String

    LastRow = Worksheets("HP Service Manager").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
        CellValue = Worksheets("HP Service Manager").Cells(i, "E").Value

        If CellValue = "" Then
            Worksheets("HP Service Manager").Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
```

End Sub